# Query with only in where?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there keyword like 'only' in sqlite? I have to write a query to display the sailor name who have reserved only red boat. So my current query is:

```
select s.sname
from sailor s, boat b, reservation r
where s.sname = r.sname
and b.bname = r.bname
and b.color = 'red';
```

The problem with the query above is it also display the sailor name who reserve red + other color boat. My query result:

```
a reserve red boat
a reserve green boat
b reserve red boat
```

but it should display only b since he only reserve red boat.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` clause to filter the sailor with only `red` boat.

```
select r.sname
from reservation r
join boat b
on b.bname = r.bname
and b.color = 'red'
and not exists ( select 1 from reservation r2
                 join boat b2
                 on r2.bname = b2.bname
                 and r2.sname = r.sname
                 and b2.color <> 'red' )
```

Comment: Thank you, but it also display sailor who select other color boat.

Comment: @something, i tried it , it was giving correct results, here is the sql fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/dbaa2/1

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple option present. You can use a `NOT IN` operator like

```
select s.sname
from sailor s, boat b, reservation r
where s.sname = r.sname
and b.bname = r.bname
and b.color NOT IN (select distinct color from boat where color <> 'red');
```

Also, not every sailor will reserve a boat. So in that case, you better off for a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Also, I think you meant to do a `group by` sailor name something like below

```
select s.sname
from sailor s, 
left join reservation r on s.sname = r.sname
left join boat b on b.bname = r.bname
group by s.sname
having count(*) <= 1 and b.color = 'red'
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both of your queries, but it results as same as I have with my query.